# How find line containing string print it + x lines after

Tags: grep

I have a log that constantly throws data to the screen. I need to catch a line that contains a certain string, print it and the next 5 lines afterward.
It easy to do with a static file like:
grep -A 5 "XXX" /mnt/flash/logs/system/messages

Comment: Your title should say that the file keeps changing.. You show in your question that you know the answer to the question asked in your title (grep -A). But the body of the question shows that you mean for a file that is changing.

Comment: Also, re your question, what about putting that grep line in a loop?

Comment: Also, since you know how to print lines after a string (e.g. grep -A 5)  Why don't you  just ask how to find and print a line of a file that keeps changing? (And forget about asking about lines after 'cos you already know that).

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -f /mnt/flash/logs/system/messages | grep -A 5 "XXX"
```

About [`tail -f`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html):

> `-f`
>   If the input file is a regular file or if the file operand specifies a FIFO, do not terminate after the last line of the input file has been copied, but read and copy further bytes from the input file when they become available. […]

You already know `grep -A`. Note it's not portable ([`-A` is not required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)) while `tail -f` is.

Since it's common to rotate logs, you may find `find --follow=name` approach more useful. Your `find` may or may not support it, check `man 1 find` in your OS.